# Using residue theorem along a branch cut to evaluate the inverse Laplace transform

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $f(z)$ using the residue theorem. Can you please check to see if what am doing below is correct? I am not really sure about what I am doing. Thanks.

$$f(z) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{z}}}{z-1}$$

My attempt:

I calculated the residue at the pole/singularity at $z = 1$ as follows:

$$e^{zt}f(z)=\lim_{z\to 1} (z-1)\frac{e^{zt}e^{-\sqrt{z}}}{z-1} = e^{t-1}$$

Next I need to evaluate the integral at the branch cut, i.e, at $z = 0$:

$$z = re^{i\theta} = re^{\frac{i\pi}{2}},$$

I reckon since its a d-shaped contour from $R \to 0$ should be $\theta = \pi/2$,

$$\implies z = ir \therefore \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{ir},$$

so now along the branch cut have:

$$\int e^{zt}f(z)dz = \int \frac{e^{zt}e^{-\sqrt{z}}}{z-1}dz = \int \frac{e^{irt}e^{-\sqrt{ir}}}{ir-1}idr$$

and for $\theta = -\pi/2$ have the following:

$$z = re^{i\theta} = re^{\frac{-i\pi}{2}}.$$

I reckon we now along contour from $0 \to R$ should be $\theta = -\pi/2$:

$$\implies z = -ir \therefore \sqrt{z} = -\sqrt{ir}.$$

So now along the branch cut have:

$$\int e^{zt}f(z)dz = \int \frac{e^{zt}e^{-\sqrt{z}}}{z-1}dz = \int \frac{e^{irt}e^{\sqrt{ir}}}{-ir-1}(-idr)$$

Comment: Hello. Please don't use so much italics and boldfaces in your text. It is distracting and makes it harder to read. I've edited your post and added relevant tags. Good luck!